# How should I clean up variables when a buffer with my major mode is buried or killed?

Tags: variables, emacs

I'm writing a major mode for a buffer that is created in response to an interactive command. In other words, there is going to be only 1 buffer with this major mode active. Something like the `messages-mode-buffer` or Magit's Status buffer.

The problem is that even after the buffer with my major mode is killed, the variables I have defined with `defvar` stick around with their last values.

Is this normal? Looking at some other modes randomly, I also don't see them collecting variables that they had used but don't need any more.

If I should clean these up, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable has the same value in every buffer, then it obviously needs to survive when a buffer is killed. It may apply to other existing buffers, and even if all buffers in this mode are killed, it will apply to new buffers in that mode. So the question only applies to variables that have a local value that may differ in every buffer.

In order to have a local value in a buffer, the variable needs to be [explicitly made local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Creating-Buffer_002dLocal). This is typically done either by calling `make-local-variable` if the variable needs to be local in a given buffer, or by calling `make-variable-buffer-local` immediately after `defvar` to declare that all assignments to that variable (except with `set-default` and the like) will be local.

If a buffer is buried, that doesn't affect its variables in any way. Burying a buffer is just about the visibility of a window displaying it.

If a buffer is killed, then all of its local variable values stop existing.

This only leaves the case when an existing buffer changes its major mode. All [major mode functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html#Major-Mode-Conventions) must call `kill-all-local-variables`. This removes any local variable value that was meaningful for the previous mode.